# Unity cannot find any android devices

Tags: android, list, unity-game-engine, device, build-error

When trying to build the apk to my galaxy S4 it give me the error that it cant find any android devices in the list of devices.
[Unity error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dPT0.jpg)

I have all settings correct.
- My Android SDK path is correct,
- my JDK path is correct,
- Even the google USB driver is downloaded and installed (trough the SDK manager).
-The developer option on my phone is on and USB debugging is checked.
-I tried updating the driver to my S4 phone trough Device Manager, but it said it was already up to date.
- My phone is recognized in windows when checking "My Computer". I can browse trough my S4 files, no problems. I can manually set the apk file on my phone.

All settings i can think off or found trough other solutions are correctly set. Still, im getting the problem that it cannot build to my S4 galaxy.
Some suggestions say to kill adb kill-server and restart it again..or go to task manager and do that. I cannot find the adb service/proces in the taskmanager, nor are the command reqonized in CMD prompt. (Running windows 7)

I have no clue anymore what causes it. Anyone any idea here?

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause is that you're missing the ADB driver for your phone. This can be the case even though it's listed in Device Manager and you can access the phones files.

Try installing this driver: http://download.clockworkmod.com/test/UniversalAdbDriverSetup6.msi

Once it's installed you should see another entry in the Device Manager list like this:
[image: Device manager screenshot of the ADB listing]

Comment: I dont think that was a problem because the devices was already working. No problems were in the Device managers to be seen. But to be sure i tried your solution anyways.
[link](http://imgur.com/a/daPgf) and [link](http://imgur.com/a/fW9vV)**

Results : Unity still does not find any devices, though i can see the working device list in "My Computer"

I also tried adb in CMD, but the commands are not reqonized.